# Django dates getting sorted wrong DRF

Tags: python, django, date, django-rest-framework

I have a django models-

```
class CompanyForLineCharts(models.Model):
  company = models.TextField(null=True)

class LineChartData(models.Model):
  foundation = models.ForeignKey(CompanyForLineCharts, null=True)
  date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
  price = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

And views for these models-

```
arr = []
for i in range(len(entereddate)):
  date = entereddate[i]
  if entereddate[i] in dates:
    foundat = (dates.index(entereddate[i]))
  allprices = Endday.objects.raw("SELECT id, eop FROM drf_endday where company=%s", [comp[i]])
  allendofdayprices = ''
  for a in allprices:
    allendofdayprices=(a.eop)
    tempprices = allendofdayprices.split(',')
    stringprices = tempprices[foundat:]
    finald = dates[foundat:]
    finalp = []
    for t in range(len(stringprices)):
      finalp.append(float(re.sub(r'[^0-9.]', '', stringprices[t])))
      company = CompanyForLineCharts.objects.get(company=comp[i])
    for j in range(len(finalp)):
      arr.append(
         LineChartData(
           foundation = company,
           date = finald[j],
           price = finalp[j]
         )
      )
LineChartData.objects.bulk_create(arr)
```

Where `entereddate` is a list of dates(date object) entered by the user, `dates` is a big list of dates(also date object, in chronological order) and `tempprices` is a list of prices that corresponds to the `dates` list.

I have a serializer setup for these-

```
class LineChartDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = LineChartData
    fields = ('date','price')

class CompanyForLineChartsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 data = LineChartDataSerializer(many=True, source='linechartdata_set')
   class Meta:
   model = CompanyForLineCharts
   fields = ('company', 'data')
```

As you see `LineChartData` model is associated to `CompanyForLineCharts` model via `foundation`.

Now the problem that I'm facing is when drf serialises these fields, the order of dates go haywire.

So I tried these as well-

- In views-

  `xy = zip(finald, finalp)
  sort = sorted(xy)
  finald = [x[0] for x in sort]
  finalp = [x[1] for x in sort]`

  Well, that did not change any order in the serialised output.
- So I tried ordering serializer-

  `order_by = (('date',))
   ordering = ['-date']`

And none of them worked. What to do now?

Answer (score 0):

@edit I'm sorry, but it shouldn't change anything I just checked Documentation and default values of `auto_now_add` and `auto_now` are `False`. 
`DateField(auto_now_add=False)` -> `DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)` should solve your problem.
If `auto_now` is true then it set date everytime when `.save()` method is called. `auto_now_add` do the same when you call constructor.
`auto_now` is used when you want date of last modification, while `auto_now_add` when you need date of creation.
You're not in any of these causes so you needs to set boths argumments as `False`

Comment: Nope, didn't do it.